# Generating a tag cloud in acts_as_taggable_on in Rails it prints out raw text of the tags info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my html page where i want to publish the tag cloud I place this

```
<div id="tag_cloud">
    <%=  tag_cloud Post.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
       <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
    <% end %>
</div>      `
```

and it outputs the tag cloud just fine, but also, immediately below the cloud, this:

```
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "apollo", taggings_count: 3>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "fintech", taggings_count: 2>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "hipsum", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 4, name: "Illya", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 5, name: "Ukrainian", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 6, name: "fb", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 7, name: "medium", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 8, name: "startups", taggings_count: 2>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 9, name: "colin", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 10, name: "people", taggings_count: 2>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 11, name: "money", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 12, name: "snape", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 13, name: "harry potter", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 14, name: "drake", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 15, name: "resources", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 16, name: "growth", taggings_count: 1>, #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 17, name: "customer aquisition", taggings_count: 1>]
```

when i remove the `link_to` line, it JUST outputs the garbage text below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have printed tag_cloud as well. use this

```
      <%  tag_cloud Post.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
      <% end %>
```